# $location.search() is not working - AngularJs 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, parameters

I want to get the query string values. I am using $location.search() to get those values but it says that $location.search is not a function. I am using 1.5 version of AngularJs.

JS -

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);   
}]);


app.controller('myCtrl',[ '$location','$scope', function($scope, $location){
       var searchObject = $location.search();   
       console.log('searchObject');   
       console.log(searchObject); 
}]);
```

I don't understand what I am missing in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course it's not a function, because you are calling `search` method on the `$scope` object. The order of the services you inject into controller is `$location` then `$scope`. So what you called `$location` in controller is actually a `$scope`. Order is important.

Correct dependency injection should be:

```
[ '$location', '$scope', function($location, $scope) {
```